# How to access first level keys of a 2d array with a foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, key

How do I access the first level key of a two-dimensional array using a foreach loop?

I have a `$places` array like this:

```
[Philadelphia] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [place_name] => XYX
                    [place_id] => 103200
                    [place_status] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                [place_name] => YYYY
                [place_id] => 232323
                [place_status] => 0
            )
```

This is my view code that loops over the array:

```
<?php foreach($places as $site): ?>
    <h5><?=key($site)?></h5>
        <?php foreach($site as $place): ?>
            <h6><?=$place['place_name']?></h6>
        <?php endforeach?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Where I call `key($site)`, I want to get `Philadelphia`, but I am just getting `place_name` from each row.

Answer (score 480, accepted):

You can access your array keys like so:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

Answer (score 44):

As Pekka stated above

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
```

Also you might want to try a recursive function

```
displayRecursiveResults($site);

function displayRecursiveResults($arrayObject) {
    foreach($arrayObject as $key=>$data) {
        if(is_array($data)) {
            displayRecursiveResults($data);
        } elseif(is_object($data)) {
            displayRecursiveResults($data);
        } else {
            echo "Key: ".$key." Data: ".$data."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also use `array_keys()` . Newbie friendly:

```
$keys = array_keys($arrayToWalk);
$arraySize = count($arrayToWalk); 

for($i=0; $i < $arraySize; $i++) {
    echo '<option value="' . $keys[$i] . '">' . $arrayToWalk[$keys[$i]] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: Simpler more efficient code once you have `$keys`:  `foreach ($keys as $key) ... $key ... $arrayToWalk[$key] ...`   This is useful when `$keys` might be only a few of the keys in the array - otherwise `foreach ($arrayToWalk as $key => $value) ...` is both easier to use and slightly faster.

Answer (score 10):

```
foreach($shipmentarr as $index=>$val){    
    $additionalService = array();

    foreach($additionalService[$index] as $key => $value) {

        array_push($additionalService,$value);

    }
}
```