# foreach($_SESSION AS $value){...} -> get array key of session

Tags: php, arrays, session

I fill a session like this:

```
$_SESSION[$id]=$value;
```

And I'm reading out the array with this:

```
foreach($_SESSION AS $value){...}
```

But how can I read out the `$id` of the session too? Array key?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP foreach loop key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834703/php-foreach-loop-key-value)

Answer (score 6):

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value){
}
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 4):

You need something like the following:

```
foreach($_SESSION AS $key => $value) {
  echo "$key -> $value";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
  print $key . '<br>';
  print $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value) {
  echo $key ;
  echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```php
session_start();
$dataArray = [];
//foreach(.......) can you passed your array value
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    $myData = [];
    //can you change  ['name']
    $myData["name"] = $post->name;
    $myData["email"] = $post->email;

    $dataArray[] = $myData;
}
$_SESSION["getAllarrydata"] = $dataArray;
//can you call other page
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
```

Comment: When you call this to other page ?
must use session_start();

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();
/*$array = array(0 => "Value");*/
$array[0] = "Value";
$_SESSION["array"] = $array;
/*$_SESSION["array"][0]= "Value 2";*/
foreach($_SESSION["array"] as $key => $value){
  print $key;
  print $value;
}
```

Comment: Please add comments at what your code does and why someone should write it like this