# (PHP, JSON) Foreach

Tags: php, json

I have a question about php and json. Im running this php in foreach loop. But when i get all the tank_id from the json file. I get results like

> 8011819314145

I want it to display like:
Tank ID: 801
Tank ID: 18193
Tank ID: 14145

What i'm doing wrong? Help me thank you.

Here is my php file:

```php
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/tanks/?application_id=demo&account_id=521997295");
    $json_tank = json_decode($json, TRUE);
    foreach ($json_tank['521997295'] as $tank_id) {
        echo $tank_id['tank_id'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: foreach ($array as $key => $value) dublicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834703/php-foreach-loop-key-value and many more. Lol also you can put "Tank ID:" as a static text like @Rajdeep Paul properly points out

Comment: Instead of `echo $tank_id['tank_id'];` do this, `echo "Tank ID:" . $tank_id['tank_id'] . "<br />";`

Comment: if i use this json url in loop is this right? example: `$json = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/tanks/?application_id=demo&account_id=521997295&tank_id=" . $tank_id['tank_id']);`

Comment: You don't have to change any url, just change the `echo` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/tanks/?application_id=demo&account_id=521997295");
$json_tank = json_decode($json, TRUE);
echo('<pre>');
//print_r($json_tank);
foreach ($json_tank['data']['521997295'] as $tank_id) {
echo "Tank ID: " . $tank_id['tank_id'] . '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In a `foreach` you can get both the `key` and the `value`. Take a look at the following pseudo-code

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.': '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to format output as you want.

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks.eu/wot/account/tanks/?application_id=demo&account_id=521997295");
$json_tank = json_decode($json, TRUE);
foreach ($json_tank['521997295'] as $tank_id) {
echo 'Tank ID: '.$tank_id['tank_id'].' ';
}
?>
```